# Get the original color filter of a drawable

Tags: java, android

I am trying to figure out the original colours used in controls such as Switches or ImageView (presence_online).

[image]

I thought about using the `getColorFilter()` but according to the documentation:

> Returns the current color filter, or null if none set.

Since I set none, I am getting null.

How do I get the colours used in those controls?

Comment: `"Since I set none, I am getting null."` so what "original color filter" do you want to get?

Comment: I actually want to get the hex for that pink in the example image

Comment: you cannot do that directly, but you can try using https://developer.android.com/training/material/palette-colors.html

Comment: You can get a pixel's color in your Bitmap, by using `getPixel()`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel(int,%20int)